# Parse XML into data structures, with a reversible common definition?

Tags: xml, parsing, haskell, serialization

Might any of you know of a library that can parse XML in the following way into
data structures?

```
parseXML
  [xmldef| <a>Int</a>[<b>String</b>] |]
  "<a>1</a><b>Hello</b><b>World</b>"
  == (1, ["Hello", "World"])
```

The key here is that the parser takes a definition that is descriptive enough
to deal with missing elements, lists of elements, and turn them into native data structures.

I find the idea of this definition very attractive, and perceive it to be
potentially very robust. E.g. it could be reversible as well to render XML.

```
renderXML
  [xmldef| <a>Int</a>[<b>String</b>] |]
  (1, ["Hello", "World"])
  == "<a>1</a><b>Hello</b><b>World</b>"
```

Here is another example on how I imagine this could work:

```
data Coord = Coord Int Int
instance XMLDef Coord where
  xmlDefinition = [xmldef| <x>Int</x><y>Int</y> |]


coordsDef = [xmldef| [<coord>Coord</coord>] |] 

parseXML coordsDef "" == []
parseXML coordsDef longXML == [Coord 1 2, Coord 3 4]
longXML = "<coord><x>1</x><y>2</y></coord><coord><x>3</x><y>4</y></coord>"

renderXML coordsDef [Coord 5 6] == "<coord><x>5</x><y>6</y></coord>"
```

Quite succinct and powerful notation, it seems. Does something like this
exist for Haskell?
Or for any other language for that matter?

I know about [this library (named 'syntax')](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syntax)
So maybe it could be used to build the above mentioned API if no other option
exists at this point.

#### So far

I've used [the library named 'xml'](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml), which is fine for simple tasks,
but it has two downsides: It doesn't support a common definition to both parse
and render XML, and it gets quite a bit more verbose than the syntax I outline
above in my experience.

While looking around, I found that haxml, hxt and hexpat are also popular
choices. However they too seem to be limited in the same way: No reversible
definitions supported, and quite a bit more verbose than what I am looking for
with this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an implementation of a [bidirectional JSON parser in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JsonGrammar), so it may be possible to implement a reversible XML parser using a similar approach. There is also a domain-specific language called [BIGUL](https://books.google.com/books?id=jH1TDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=haskell+%22bidirectional%22+parsing&source=bl&ots=HS4XLPi9JC&sig=MUIL3V_17ZUCTrgZj9jUbPTnZf8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3kZXjt5zaAhXBmOAKHZrqAJYQ6AEIczAK#v=onepage&q=haskell%20%22bidirectional%22%20parsing&f=false) that can be used to implement reversible parsers in Haskell.